# prove $OK+KH=OL+LH$

Tags: geometry

let $O, H$ be circumcircle and orthocenter of triangle $\triangle ABC$ which in $\angle C=45^\circ $. we draw a line passing throw $O$ and perpendicular to $CO$ to meet $AC, BC$ at $K, L$ respectively prove $OK+KH=OL+LH$

my attempts:

let $M, N$ be orthocenter and the foot of attitude from $K$ to $LC$ in $\triangle KCL$.we will have:
$OK=cos\angle OKM.KM$

$OL=cos\angle MLO.LM$

$cos\angle MLO=\frac{OC}{\sqrt{2}KN}$ , $cos\angle OKM=\frac{KN}{LK}$

hence $OL-OK=\frac{OC.LN}{KN}-\frac{KN.KM}{MC}=\frac{2S_{\triangle KCL}.LN-2S_{\triangle KNC}.KM}{KN.MC}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}KC(LC.MN-KN.KM)}{KN.MC}$
therefore we have to prove:

$LC.MN+KL.LH=KL.KH+KN.KM$

but I don't know how to continue.
please share your ideas in comments and post an answer even if your solution isn't complete.thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proof

Let $AH,BH$ intersect the circumcircle $(ABC)$ at second points $E,F$ respectively. Then

$$\angle COE=2\angle CAE=2\times 45^o=90^o,~~~\angle COF=2\angle CBF=2\times 45^o=90^o,~~~$$ which implies that $E,L,O,K,F$ are colinear.

Notice that $H,E$ are symmetric with respect to $BC$, and so are $H,F$ with respect to $AC$. Hence $$OL+LH=OL+LE=OE,~~~OK+KH=OK+KF=OF.$$

But $OE,OF$ are both the radiuses of $(ABC)$. Hence $$OE=OF,$$ which implies the conclusion you want to prove.

[image]